# Issues with starting work before Shacharis

Tags: halacha, time, employment, shacharis-morning-prayer

What are the halachic issues/opinions/options regarding starting work early, i.e. before one is allowed or practically able to daven Shachris?

Answer (score 3):

*See* Rabbi Gil Student, [Shacharis Tips of the Unemployed](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2009/03/shacharis-tips-of-unemployed.html), *Hirhurim*:

> I. Earliest Times for Shacharis
>
> The general rule is that Shacharis can
>   only be prayed (at or) after sunrise
>   (Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chaim 89:1),
>   ...
>   Bedi'eved, if you prayed after dawn,
>   you fulfilled your obligation. But
>   really you are supposed to wait until
>   after sunrise. 
>   (Dawn is
>   calculated differently by different
>   authorities.) ....
>
> However, someone who has to leave on a
>   trip before sunrise is allowed to pray
>   in that period between dawn and
>   sunrise (Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chaim
>   89:8). Contemporary authorities
>   categorize a commute to work as a trip
>   for these purposes, and when I was
>   commuting to yeshiva from Brooklyn to
>   Washington Heights I was told by my
>   rosh yeshiva that this was also
>   sufficient reason for praying before
>   sunrise.

In New York, during much of the year, dawn is between 4:15-4:30am (although at times, it does get close to 6:00am). If one does start work before dawn, it would be permitted to work until dawn. However, one is not allowed to do work-like activities after dawn if one has not yet prayed (*see Tefillah Ke-Hilkhasah*, ch. 6 and *Law of Daily Living* vol. 1, ch. 11).

One exception discussed by Rabbi Student would be if one has a set minyan. He also discusses dissenting opinions that do not allow for this exception. One might therefore surmise according to the lenient position that someone could start work at 4:00am today if he has a set minyan at 10:00am (prior to the conclusion of the time for prayer, or, forgoing timely prayer, until midday).

For zmanim in your area, please see [MyZmanim.com](http://www.myzmanim.com/).

Of course, if you're confronted with this situation in practice, you should consult your Rabbi to determine what to do.

Comment: Isaac, I was typing up a disclaimer, but then I saw the bright red disclaimer on the top of the page.  Didn't want to be redundant.

Comment: Redundancy in the service of Halachic caution is no vice. Not everyone necessarily notices or remembers the notice at the top. The more practically-oriented questions, especially those that deal with matters about which the authorities disagree or where the nuances of the situation are important, deserve a little additional caution.

Comment: You're absolutely right.