# What prayers might be permissible or not permissible to pray before dawn?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, shacharis-morning-prayer, employment, morning-day

I have a question that is similar to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/issues-with-starting-work-before-shacharis/1253#) one, but a little different. Like many people, I have a job that I currently have to be at (with location and time of year factored in) at around dawn. Hence, my questions. What are the prayers (besides the Shema, the blessings surrounding the Shema, and the Shmonei Esrei) that should be omitted before dawn? This question can go the other way too. Are there any prayers that can be prayed before dawn? What are they? I know that Psalms are an option, but my question relates to the prayers in the Siddur... in my mind anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Prayers in the siddur that can be said before dawn:

From [Tefila Kehilchata](http://www.zolsefer.co.il/171616/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%94)

3 (8) If you get up after (halachic) midnight, you can say the morning blessings, except (1) “Elokai Neshomo ..” (2) “Hamaavir sheina” which can be said without Shem and Malchus and (3) “Hanosain Lasechvi” which should only be said after dawn. [(O Ch 47 (13) MB [30])](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=153)

3 (11) Korbonos: the parsha of the “kiyor” (washing hands and feet) and “terumas hadeshen” (removing ashes) can be said at night. When necessary all the  Korbonos can be said at night. [(O Ch 1 (6) MB [17])](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=9)

Comment: Is this exhaustive? (I'd be surprised to learn one can't say Psalm 30 e.g.)

Comment: @msh210 That's all I found in Tefila Kehilchata.

Comment: Another prayer that can be recited before dawn is Maariv.